# Running Java files on VS Code flashes a CMD and shows no output

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I'm new to Java and already installed the extensions that VS Code suggests, however, when I try to run my code (it's just a "Hello World") a CMD appears for less than a second and then no output is shown. I also tried an online compiler and the code ran just fine. I reinstalled VS Code and JDK but that didn't solve the problem. Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am guessing, that vscode is running your code in a new console window each time. when your code is finished, the console window closes again. i don't use vscode, but there is probably a way to run the code in the vscode-terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Before you change the relevant settings, the result of running the code in VS Code should be output in the terminal.

[image]

Please use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open the command palette, then search for and select **Preferences: Open Settings(JSOn)**. See what settings have been modified in the file.

[image]

Also, follow this [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-tutorial) to start writing Java code with VS Code.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. I checked the JSON file and no settings have been modified. After trying a few things I figured out the problem comes from Java and not VS Code. When I use a CMD to run java commands like "java -version" it also flashes a new CMD and doesn't print the version (happens with every command).

Comment: How are you running your code?